# Does cancellation law hold after epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume we have two structures $(P,\cdot)$, $(Q, \ast)$, and a epimorphism $f:P\to Q$.

If the cancellation law holds in $P$, i.e., $\forall a, b, c\in P, ab=ac\Rightarrow b=c$, can we conclude that the cancellation law also holds in $Q$?

I tried some semigroups, like $(\mathbb{Z},∗)$ or all the square matrix with matrix multiplication. I also try some non associative operation, such as cross product. However, after I construct $Q$, I fail to construct a cancellable $P$ as well as the epimorphism.

In my mind there should be some counterexamples because in $P$ the structures is more fine-grained, which makes the cancellation holds more easily. However, the $f(b)=f(c)$ also becomes easier in a corser level.

Comment: Why do you think it might? What examples have you tried?

Comment: I think there should be some counter examples but I fail to find one. The hardest part is that we have little knowledge about the structure in $P$.

Comment: Well, what structures do you know what fails to have the cancellation law? That is, what could you choose for $Q$?

Comment: I tried some semigroups, like $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ or all the square matrix with matrix multiplication. I also try some non associative operation, such as cross product. However, after I construct $Q$, I fail to construct a cancellable $P$ as well as the epimorphism.

Comment: By "epimorphism", do you mean "surjective homomorphism"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I'll give you a counterexample. There might be simpler or more natural examples, but this is the first one I thought of.

Let $p\colon \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection (sometimes called a pairing function).

Let $P=(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N},\cdot)$, with the operation defined by $(a,a')\cdot (b,b')=(p(b,b'),0)$. This satisfies the cancellation law: if $(a,a')\cdot (b,b')=(a,a')\cdot (c,c')$, then $p(b,b')=p(c,c')$, so $(b,b')=(c,c')$ since $p$ is a bijection.

Let $Q=(\mathbb{N},*)$, with the operation defined by $a*b=0$ for all $a$ and $b$. This does not satisfy the cancellation law. For example, $0*1=0=0*0$, but $1\neq 0$.

Now let $f\colon P\to Q$ be the second projection: $f(a,a')=a'$. This is surjective, so it remains to show it is a homomorphism. Indeed, we have: $$f((a,a')\cdot (b,b'))=f(p(b,b'),0)=0=f(a,a')*f(b,b').$$

**Added:** Here's an example that's commutative and somewhat more elementary.

Let $P=(\mathbb{N},+)$. This satisfies the cancellation law.

Let $Q=(\{0,\infty\},*)$, where $0*0=0$ and $x*\infty=\infty*x=\infty$ for all $x$. This does not satisfy the cancellation law.

Define $f\colon P\to Q$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)=\infty$ for all $n>0$. Then $f$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your construction. I had come up with a similar $Q=(\{-1,1\},*)$ before but failed to make it not satisfy the cancellation law. I think $Q=(\{0,1\},*)$ might be easier since we do not need to define the operation $*$ for $\infty$, though they are exactly the same.

Comment: The idea of packing is really interesting... I should have come up with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Another example which might be simpler that the one in Alex's answer or not, depending on what you know, is the following.

Let $\mathbf S(x,y,z)$ be the free semigroup on the set of generators $\{x,y,z\}$.
This certainly satisfies the cancellation law.

Now take the congruence $\theta = \Theta(xy,xz)$.
In $\mathbf S/\theta$, we have $xy = xz$, but not $y=z$, so it doesn't satisfy the cancellation law.
On the other hand, it's quite clear that $\mathbf S/\theta$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbf S$, via the natural homomorphism $\nu_{\theta}:s\mapsto s/\theta$.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that might be simpler, but to me I have to understand free semigroup and congruence (I can somehow guess their meanings but need to verify that tomorrow.

Comment: @VicaYang I understand your position, and that's what I meant in the first paragraph. Either you know, and this is the most straightforward answer, or you don't and then an answer like Alex's have it all explained. Best wishes :)